# dotenv preventing build in production

Tags: reactjs, travis-ci, create-react-app, netlify

I am using create-react-app, Travis CI and netlify. I have a config file that looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').load();

module.exports = {
    API_BASE_URL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8080'
}
```

When I try to deploy to Netlify, I get this error in Travis:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Failed to minify the code from this file: 
    ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js:23
```

If I remove the require('dotenv').load(); part, it loads, but then the app tries to go to localhost, which is obviously not what I want.

This article: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/261

brings up the same issue, but they don't offer a solution. I'm stuck. Help!

Comment: Hmm - the comment on that issue is reasonable - why ARE you minifying a node system tool?  That is not intended to be published on the web.

Answer (score 4):

disclaimer:  I work for netlify.

TL;DR unix shells complicate things.

The preferred way to use environment variables in Netlify is to set them in our environment - be that in the Build Environment Variables configuration widget (second on the "Build & Deploy settings" page - under your the repo+build command section), or via netlify.toml (https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#deploy-contexts).  The latter is a bit more flexible as you can set different values for different contexts - e.g. staging uses a staging DATABASE_URL and production uses a production one.

So - those variables are "available" in the build environment - if your build command were `env`, then you'd see them - in addition to $PATH and $NODE_VERSION and some other stuff Netlify sets automatically.  However, depending on how your build pipeline works, they may or not be available inside of it.  If your build command is `node -p "process.env"` - that will show you what node sees for environment variables - and that should show the same thing as `env` shows (which is what the shell run by the [build script](https://github.com/netlify/build-image/blob/master/run-build-functions.sh) sees).

Unfortunately, many of the build pipelines that folks use DON'T automatically import/inherit variables from the parent shells.  This thread shows such an example:  https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/136#issue-26148596 .  So - the best practice is not to necessarily use something like dotenv (though that has worked for folks that aren't trying to minify it :) ) - but instead, use a build process that appropriately passes those environment variables that we expose in the shell, into the build environment.  How you do that is kind of up to you and your tools.

a further PS: unless your build pipeline DOES something with the environment variable - it's not going to be much use in the code that gets published and served to the browser - which doesn't understand `$REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL` - that's just a string to the browser.  I know you're not trying to do that, but wanted to point it out for folks who might see this answer later - it's a common misunderstanding among newer developers of static sites.

Comment: The issue seems to be more with Travis than Netlify. I have env variables set in Netlify. If they could GET there, I think it would work fine